How to solve complex equations numerically in Python?
Originally, I had the following equation:
2mgv×sin(\alpha) = CdA×\rho(v^2 + v_{wind}^2 + 2vv_{wind}cos(\phi))^(3/2)


which I could express as the following non-linear equation:
(K × v)^(2/3) = v^2 + v_{wind} + 2vv_{wind}cos(\phi)

To solve this, I need to use a numerical approach.
I tried writing a code for this in Python using fsolve from scipy.optimize. However, the results I got are not too promising. What else should I try? Should I use a different approach/package or just my code needs to be improved? I also experienced that the result is highly dependent on v_initial_guess.
Please note, that I would consider myself as a beginner in programming.
I also tried writing a code to solve the equation for v using the Newton-Raphson method but I wasnt too successful.
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

m = 80
g = 9.81  
alpha = np.radians(10)  #incline
CdA = 0.65 
rho = 1.225  
v_w = 10  
phi = np.radians(30)    #wind angle with the direction of motion

sin_alpha = np.sin(alpha)
cos_phi = np.cos(phi)


def equation(v):
    K = ((m * g * sin_alpha) / ((CdA * rho))**(2/3))
    return K * v**(2/3) - v**2 - 2*v*v_w*cos_phi - v_w**2

v_initial_guess = 30


v_solution = fsolve(equation, v_initial_guess, xtol=1e-3)

print("v:", v_solution[0])type here

EDIT:
This is what my code looks like now:
    import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


m = 80
g = 9.81  
alpha = np.radians(2)  # incline
CdA = 0.321 
rho = 1.22
v_w = 5
phi = np.radians(180)  # wind angle with the direction of motion

sin_alpha = np.sin(alpha)
cos_phi = np.cos(phi)

def lhs(v):
    return  m * g * v * sin_alpha

def rhs(v):
    return 0.5 * CdA * rho * (v**2 + v_w**2 + 2*v*v_w*cos_phi)**(3)

def difference(v):
    return lhs(v) - rhs(v)

# fsolve to find the intersection
v_initial_guess = 8
v_intersection = fsolve(difference, v_initial_guess)[0]

v_values = np.linspace(0.1, 50, 500)

lhs_values = lhs(v_values)
rhs_values = rhs(v_values)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(v_values, lhs_values, label='$2mgv\\sin(\\alpha)$', color='blue')
plt.plot(v_values, rhs_values, label='$CdA\\rho(v^2 + v_{wind}^2 + 2vv_{wind}\\cos(\\phi))^{3/2}$', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Velocity (v)')
plt.xlim(0, 20)
plt.title('LHS and RHS vs. Velocity')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(0, 2000)
plt.show()

print(f"The intersection occurs at v = {v_intersection:.2f} m/s")

P_grav_check = m *g * sin_alpha * v_intersection
P_air_check = 0.5 * CdA * rho * (v_intersection ** 2 + v_w ** 2 + 2 * v_intersection * v_w * cos_phi) ** (3)

print(P_grav_check)
print(P_air_check)


I think your expression for K in code is wrong. It's overbracketed and the exponent of (2/3) should be applying to all of it. When you fix that you can plot the LHS and RHS of your original equation against v - they don't intersect, so there are no solutions for your given parameters. It's never a bad idea to plot graphs for your equations to get a handle on what's going on. Finally, I'm not convinced by your original equation: it is effectively saying "weight x velocity" = "drag force x velocity" - a bit unlikely. "Component of weight = drag (or, better, lift)" would seem better.

I wasnt too successful. What exactly were the results?

@ryanwebjackson I think due to unknown reasons the algorithm was trying to use negative v values (RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar power
return K * v**(2/3) - (v2 + v_w2 + 2vv_w*cos_phi)), so it was not working at all. Unfortunately, I can't copy my code for the Newton-Raphson approach here, it is too long.

@lastchance Thank you for the advice! First of all, I see your concern regarding overbracketing. I corrected the code and also multiplied the left handside by 2 (I realized that I made a mistake there) and now it seemingly works better, however, the results still seem to be incorrect. On the other hand, I don't understand your concerns regarding the equation, on the left handside 2mgsin(alpha)*v stands, which is power against the gravitational force multiplied by 2.

Please edit your post to indicate the changes that you have made; the current post is not in line with your comments. Also, explain “the results still seem to be incorrect”. Also, plot a graph showing two curves: the LHS of your original equation against v and the RHS of your original equation against v. This will indicate whether you have ANY solutions with your current parameters. (Prior to your reinsertion of a factor 2 I found no solutions unless I greatly increased m or greatly reduced Cd. Then, there were multiple solutions on a graph.)

@lastchance So, the check I wrote into the new code seemingly verifies the calculations now. However, I am unsure about having two roots. In the exact example I gave (see my edits), the incline is set to a small number. In this case, I would expect equality at a relatively low speed, after which drag power should increase constantly proportionally. However, as you can see from the plot, it will approach zero and then rise again. I suspect something is not working with phi...

But now your code has a new error: an exponent of 3 on the RHS (equivalent to a velocity to the power 6, since there is already a velocity squared inside the bracket) and your post implies 3/2. So, you are moving even further away from even your intended equation. Please provide the source of your equations and we can try to take it from there; there's no point spending time trying to solve faulty equations.

Please see my conjecture at what you might be doing at the bottom of my edited post.

@lastchance I will write down the physics part so you can see it

The solution, using the secant method is the following:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


m = 60  
g = 9.81  
alpha = np.radians(2)  # incline 
CdA = 0.321  
rho = 1.225
v_wind = 4
phi = np.radians(60)  # wind angle with the direction of motion
mu = 0.005

cos_phi = np.cos(phi)
sin_alpha = np.sin(alpha)


lhs = m * g * sin_alpha     # gravitational force

def rhs(v):
    return 0.5 * CdA * rho * (v + v_wind *cos_phi)**2    # drag force

def difference(v):
    return lhs - rhs(v)

def secant_method(func, v0, v1, tolerance=1e-6, max_iterations=1000):
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        f_v0 = func(v0)
        f_v1 = func(v1)
        
        v_new = v1 - f_v1 * (v1 - v0) / (f_v1 - f_v0)
        if abs(v_new - v1) < tolerance:
            return v_new
        v0, v1 = v1, v_new
    raise ValueError("Secant method did not converge")

v_initial_guess_1 = 15
v_initial_guess_2 = 25
v_intersection = secant_method(difference, v_initial_guess_1, v_initial_guess_2)

v_values = np.linspace(0.1, 50, 500)
rhs_values = rhs(v_values)


P_grav_check = m * g * sin_alpha * v_intersection
P_air_check = 0.5 * CdA * rho * (v_intersection + v_wind * cos_phi)**2 * v_intersection
P_friction = mu * m * g * np.cos(alpha) * v_intersection

alpha_degree = np.degrees(alpha)
alpha_percentage = np.tan(alpha) *100

print(f"\nopposing component of v_wind: ",v_wind *cos_phi, "m/s")
print(f"The intersection occurs at v = {v_intersection:.4f} m/s")
print(f" at a {alpha_degree} degrees incline which equals to {alpha_percentage:.2f} %")
print(f"\nP_grav: {P_grav_check:.2f} W")
print(f"P_air_check: {P_air_check:.2f} W")
print(f"P_friction:  {P_friction:.2f} W")
print(f"P = {P_grav_check + P_air_check + P_friction}")


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(v_values, [lhs]*len(v_values), label='$mg\\sin(\\alpha)$', color='blue')
plt.plot(v_values, rhs_values, label='$0.5CdA\\rho ({v + v_{wind}\\cos(\\phi)})^2$', color='red')
plt.xlabel('Velocity (v)')
plt.xlim(0, 20)
plt.title('Gravitational vs. Drag Force')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(0, 200)
plt.show() 


You won't be able to get a solution with Newton-Raphson (or anything else) because ... there isn't one.
Plot graphs of the LHS and RHS of your original equation: they don't intersect (see below). So, no solution. That isn't changed by multiplying the LHS by 2,  or, more naturally, multiplying the RHS by 1/2.
Please provide a source for your original equation because, physically, it is fundamentally incorrect. You should balance forces, not power. If you want to balance power then multiply both equations by the actual velocity (v), not by v on the left, v-v_wind on the right. Also, if v is not horizontal then your drag force is wrong anyway.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 80                  # mass
g = 9.81                # gravity
alpha = np.radians(10)  # incline
CdA = 0.65              # drag coefficient times area
rho = 1.225             # density of air
v_w = 10                # wind speed
phi = np.radians(30)    # wind angle with the direction of motion

sin_alpha = np.sin(alpha)
cos_phi = np.cos(phi)

v = np.linspace( 0, 20, 101 )
LHS = m * g * v * sin_alpha           # or twice this
#LHS = 2 * m * g * v * sin_alpha      # 
RHS = CdA * rho * ( v ** 2 + v_w ** 2 + 2 * v * v_w * cos_phi ) ** 1.5

plt.plot( v, LHS, label="LHS" )
plt.plot( v, RHS, label="RHS" )
plt.xlabel( "v" )
plt.ylabel( "power" )
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Output:

You aren’t telling us where your equations come from. In the absence of that, I’m going to have a guess.
Let’s suppose you have an object, mass m and cross-sectional area A, descending (angle alpha below the horizontal) at steady speed v in a horizontal crossflow vw. In the diagram, red is a force and blue is a velocity.

If the speed is steady then weight balances drag. To do this directionally then the relative velocity U must be in the direction shown (vertically downward).

This gives a relative velocity

If you know the wind speed then the velocity and descent angle are given by Pythagoras's theorem and trigonometry:

If, on the other hand, you know the descent angle and you want to find wind speed and velocity then

If all this is wrong then ... please tell us where your equations come from!
